# Database error when uploading WordPress from WAMP to GoDaddy (cannot access site locally)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, wamp

I am by no means any bit of an expert and I am really hoping this did not just bite me! I have created a WP site on my computer locally thru WAMP. I was near completion and have a domain set up on GoDaddy that I wanted to transfer it to. This is a project that I am not always able to work on so sometimes I would forget my log in info for the phpMyAdmin. I recently did a tutorial that got me to reset my password which worked for accessing the files under the phpMyAdmin however I can no longer bring up my local copy of WP without getting this error - Error establishing a database connection. Not sure if when I changed my password if this caused an issue with how the local server was set up but I am at a loss after many hours of work.

I also unfortunately am unable to log into my phpMyAdmin and wouldn't even know where to begin. This is definitely over my head as far as technicality goes as I am probably not describing this the best way possible. Can anyone with suggestions please assist if you have had database issues on a local server thru WAMP and what is the best measure to ensure I have not lost all of my hard work?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you just lost your root password reset it [MySQL reset root password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html). Which tutorial did you perform (link it)?

Answer (score 0):

From what I got the issue is the local site . If so you need to go to your wp-config file in your word-press installation folder on your local machine. Edit the file using notepad. You should see a section with this part

`/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here' );`

Edit the password and your local install should work just fine.